# Android Layout - ListView taking too much space

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-activity, fragment

Well hello there!

I ran into a problem in Android (I am also new to Android).

First of all I have 2 Fragments. 1 Fragment contains a ListView where I show the music on my phone. The 2nd Fragment has some controls.

**I want that the Fragment with the Controls stays at the bottom of the screen. The ListFragment should stick to the top of the Activity. How can I do this?**

Now I have made up the following in xml:
activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rain"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- Playlist -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/playlist_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    class="at.wireless.musicstream.fragment.PlaylistFragment" />

<!-- Separator -->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

<!-- Controls -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/control_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="at.wireless.musicstream.fragment.ControlFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I used layout_weight here, but that's not what I want, because at different screen sizes this will also take up different height. But I want the controls to have a "fixed" size (I use dp in the Fragment)

playlist_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center|top"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my control_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/albumView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/no_album_art"
    android:contentDescription="Album Art" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/actPlayingTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:text="hier titel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/actPlayingArtist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="hier artist"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />"

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rewindBtt"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playbackBtt"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skipBtt"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6iJH.png)

The ListView should take the space that the control_fragment leaves. So lets say i have a total screen height of 1000. The controls take up 200, then the ListView has 800 left.

Comment: can you post drawable layout how exactly u want? just show image in question

Comment: have added an image and an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to a RelativeLayout, this will allow your controls to stay in a fixed location, you will also need to define a height for the controls (I've set this to 200dp).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rain"
android:gravity="center|top"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- Playlist -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/playlist_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    class="at.wireless.musicstream.fragment.PlaylistFragment"
    android:layout_above="@+id/separator"/>

<!-- Separator -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/control_fragment"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

<!-- Controls -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/control_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    class="at.wireless.musicstream.fragment.ControlFragment" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow thx! I already used a RelativeLayout but I forgot to add layout_alingParentBottom. Meh! It's always the small things. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You may edit your solution and replace LinearLayout with RelativeLayout

Comment: Ha forgot to implement my own changes... Thanks for the heads up!